# IPC Socket latency fluctuation on Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, ipc

I am working on a Client-Server Architecture on a single local machine with Linux 3.16 using AF_UNIX IPC Sockets. I have implemented a send_all and recv_all Functions to ensure sending/receiving all the wanted data and I use clock_gettime() with CLOCK_MONOTONIC to make time measurement just before the send-call on the client side and after the receive-call on the server side. Every packet I send is very small (11 Byte + the struct timespec). When I calc the delta of these two values after each transmission, I get fluctuating results by the factor ~15 while the shortest is around 150µs and the longest is above 2 milliseconds. While the <200µs would be fast enough for my needs, the >2ms are already very critical, so how can this varying latency be explained and is there a way to make the latency consistently as fast as possible for Sockets?

I am using SOCK_STREAM in the initialization and I thought that Nagle's Algorithm has to do something with the problem, but TCP_NODELAY is not settable via setsockopt() when using AF_UNIX (it seems to only work in AF_INET?). Also I'm thinking about using SOCK_DGRAM, but before I jump into that (for me) new area, I would like to know if I can even solve my problem with it.

My essential Functions for the Sockets are mostly inspired by Beej's Guide, but here some code anyway:

```
/* Packet Definition */

typedef struct Packet_ {
    Byte opcode;
    Byte from;
    Byte to;
    Byte payload[8];
    timespec timestamp;
} Packet;

// Send

void send_all(SOCKET s, void* data, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char* buffer_ptr = (unsigned char*)data;
    unsigned int out_counter = 0; 
    while(out_counter < len)
    {
        out_counter += send(s, buffer_ptr, len - out_counter, 0);
    }
}


// Receive

void recv_all(SOCKET s, void* buffer, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char* buffer_ptr = (unsigned char*)buffer;
    unsigned int in_counter = 0;
    while(in_counter < len)
    {
        in_counter += recv(s, buffer_ptr + in_counter, len - in_counter, 0);
    }
}

// Set Packet Header
void setPacketHeader(Packet* packet, Byte receivers, Byte opcode)
{   
    packet->from = this->get_ident();
    packet->to = receivers;
    packet->opcode = opcode;

}

// Set Packet Payload
void setPacketPayload(Packet* packet, void* payload, int pl_size)
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &(packet->timestamp));
    memcpy(&(packet->payload), payload, pl_size);
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Unless you've got a real-time version of linux, the latency is whatever the latency is. Your program is competing for processor time with about 50 other processes that the OS is running.

Comment: OT: This `send(s, buffer_ptr, ...` shoulkd be `send(s, buffer_ptr + out_counter, ...`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Also your "real" code should really check `send()` and `recv()` for errors (`-1`) and `recv()` for client hangup (`0`).

Comment: @alk: good catch! Plus ignoring negative returns from send() is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @alk: Thanks for the find, the + out_counter was really missing in my real code

Comment: While fixing make the counters signed, best make them `ssize_t`, as that's what `send()` and `recv()` return.

Comment: Try to set real time priority to your process.

Comment: Using softwares such as LatencyTOP could help to identifying operating system latency within the kernel.